# Netbeans не видит проект

Tags: netbeans

Ситуация в следующем,я работаю в intellej ,но сейчас изучаю J2EE и учитель работает в netbeans,к видео идет сам проект в zip архиве.
так вот чтобы я не делал netbeans упорно не видит проекта в этом архиве.
даже idea  открывает,а нетбинс не хочет.
Может есть какая то магия особенная?
Версия netbeans 9.0
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нажимаю на кнопку open projet и ничего не происходит,если импортирую из zip архива -пишет нет проекта нетбинс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> я работаю в intellej ,но сейчас изучаю J2EE и учитель работает в netbeans
>   . . .
>   Версия netbeans 9.0

Попробуйте использовать ту же версию, что и преподаватель. Тем более бесплатная версия Idea (надо полагать речь идёт о ней) не поддерживает Java EE.

Есть ещё вариант: `File -> New Project -> Java -> Java Project with Exisiting Sources`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: idea у меня ultimate .попробовал ваш метод проект загрузился ,но все в ошибках,нет плагинов,плагины не качает так как 1.8 jdk ,вообщем проще вернутья в Idea ,чем голову с плагинами морочить

Comment: @Алексеевстанислав, вероятно проект был создан в старой версии. После того как NetBeans был передан от Oracle в Apache (начиная как раз с версии 9.0) к этой IDE очень много вопросов. В версии 10 многие возможности вернулись, но не все. А, так до версии 8.2 включительно NetBeans был прекрасной IDE (ИМХО).

Comment: Из-за всего этого сам сейчас работаю уже не в NetBeans, а в Eclipse.

Comment: а какая лучше версия 8.0 8.1 или 8.2?

Comment: А, в какой работает автор видеокурса? Что он советует для обучения?

Comment: Для работы 8.x использовать уже нет смысла в силу устаревания.

Comment: курсы 16 года,тема J2EE,использую только изза гласфиша.который даже с нетбинсом уже 4й раз за час отваливается